# No se muestra imagen usando código CSS

Tags: css

Tengo una carpeta con imágenes y quiero que el fondo del sitio sea una imagen. El problema es que al poner la ruta relativa la imagen no se muestra pero si pongo la url de una imagen de internet si la muestra.
Mi código css es el siguiente:

```
   body {
     margin-top: 70px;
     background-image: url("fondo.jpg");
   }
```

Answer (score 10):

Asegurate de que la imagen está en la misma carpeta en la que se encuentra el CSS (en tu caso, al no poner nada más en la ruta estás diciéndole que intente buscar la imagen en la misma carpeta en la que se encuentra el CSS). En caso contrario, tendrías que indicar la ruta relativa a la carpeta correspondiente en relación a tu fichero CSS.

Imagínate esta estructura de carpetas:

```
|
|---imagenes
|      |
|      |--- fondo.jpg
|
|------tu CSS
```

tendría que ser de esta manera:

```
background-image: url("../imagenes/fondo.jpg");
```

Answer (score 4):

Cuando hacemos un llamado por `url('')` debemos navegar por archivos y carpetas.

En el caso que `url("fondo.jpg");` Lo que quiere decir es que la imagen esta en la misma carpeta del css.

Debes devolverte hacia la carpeta padre con `../` y buscar la carpeta de imagenes `../imagenes`.

El resultado sería: `url(../images/fondo.jpg);`

Creería que la estructura de su directorio es:

```
|index.html
|--css/style
|--images/fondo.jpg
```

Para devolverse a una carpeta superior `../` o puede agregar dos puntos por cada nivel que desea volver.

Algo más que puedo recomendar que te servirá a futuro y enseñará a navegar por directorios: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line

Answer (score 2):

para que no se repita la imagen colocalo de esta manera:

```
     body {
          margin-top: 70px;
          background-image: url("../fondo.jpg"");
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          }
```